# IN SQL Server how to list high and low season

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

For a database SQL Server 2008 I have a list of dates that are either in the high season, top price, or in the low season, low price.

We have only three types of duration of stay for which it is relevant, week Monday till Monday, midweek Monday till Friday, or weekend Friday till Monday.

Is it possible to say in a range that it belongs to the high season or low?
On this moment we have just a list of all possible dates and in which season it belongs.

Comment: please provide more details like table structure, sample data and the desired result. Even better create a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with a working data model.

Comment: http://www.codedump.be/code/1403/ on here you will find the complete ddl code.
Underneath you'll find the data for the table
/*==============HOOGSEIZOEN=============================================================================*/
INSERT INTO Datum VALUES  ('23-02-2001', '05-03-2001', 'hoog')
INSERT INTO Datum VALUES  ('27-04-2001', '07-05-2001', 'hoog')
INSERT INTO Datum VALUES  ('29-06-2001', '03-09-2001', 'hoog')
INSERT INTO Datum VALUES  ('21-12-2001', '07-01-2002', 'hoog')

Al other date's are low season.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.  The following gives an example of what to do, making lots of assumptions about your table formats from the limited information provided.

```
select s.stayid, 
       (case when max(d.type) = min(d.type) the min(d.type)
             when max(d.type) is null then 'NoSeason'
             else 'Mixed'
        end) as StayType
from Stays s left outer join
     Days d
     on d.date between s.start and s.end
group by s.stayid
```

This finds all the dates that correspond to a given stay.  If the types are the same (the first clause in the `case`), then it uses that.  If there are no matching days, then there is no information.  Otherwise the day types are mixed.